# ¿Como configurar rutas de frontend con AngularJS y un servidor ExpressJS?

Tags: angularjs, api, express, backend

Actualmente estoy montando una aplicación SPA, donde quiero manejar todas las rutas con AngularJS y que las rutas de Express solo sean para API, el problema que tengo es que si configuro las rutas de Angular por ejemplo:

```
http://localhost:3001/login
```

Por AngularJS (Angular 1) con una redirección le llego, pero si estoy parada en esa ruta y recargo (F5) el servidor dice que no existe esa ruta, y es claro porque no existe esa ruta en la configuración de rutas de express, ahora mi duda es **¿como configuro para que angular sea el que maneja todas las rutas?** e incluso si le doy F5 en una vista pueda continuar en ella, ¿existe alguna forma de configurar express para que las ruta las maneje el frontend y el backend solo maneje las rutas para peticiones, osea que sea netamente como API REST.

Ante todo muchas gracias de ante mano.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En una aplicación SPA, las rutas son manejadas en el cliente no en el servidor. Si haces una recarga o tipeas directamente en la barra de direcciones, lo que pasará, obviamente, es que se hará una petición `GET` al servidor, devolviéndote un 404.

Las rutas para la API deben ir primero, luego, rediriges toda petición entrante al `index.html` de tu aplicación:

**API router**

```
const router = express.Router();
router
  .get('/users', UserController.index)
  ...

export default router;
```

**App**

```
app.use(express.static(join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/api', apiRoutes);

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.type('html');
  res.sendFile(RUTA_A_index.html);
});
```

Ahora cuando recargues la página se te enviará como respuesta el `index.html` y AngularJS se encargará de renderizar la vista correcta de acuerdo a la URL.

Comment: Excelente voy a hacer la prueba, muchas gracias de verdad.

Comment: Otra duda es como es la divicion de las carpetas actualmente lo tengo así, pero tengo varios detalles.

Comment: Lo dejo como un comentario.

Comment: Perdón como una repuesta.

Answer (score 0):

```
Proyecto
|_server.js
|_public
  |_app
    |_index.hmtl
    |_module.js
    |_funcionalidad-1
      |_ruute.js
      |_module.js
      |_funcionalidad.css
      |_funcionalidad.hmlt
    |_funcionalidad-2
    :
  |_assent
|_package.json
|_bower.json
|_gulp.js
```

¿Donde coloco la parte de backend de la rutas y toda la funcionalidades? 
Tengo tambien un problema que cuando entro al servidor en la ruta `http://localhost:3001/` no se me ve nada, pero si accedo a `http://localhost:3001/app/` si funciona, no entiendo muy bien porque pasa eso.

Si me pudieran ayudar en eso se los agradecería muchísimo.

Muchas gracias.